# Word list generation (sorting, optimization)

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting

### A little background:

I'm constructing lists of words for a psychology experiment. We're trying to create a chain of words such that words adjacent in the list are related, but all other words in the list are not related. So for example:

`SCHOOL, CAFETERIA, PIZZA, CRUST, EARTH, OCEAN, WHALE, ...`

So here we see the first word is related to the second, and the second is related to the third, but the third isn't related to the first. (And the first isn't related to the fourth, fifth, sixth, ... either)

### What I have so far...

I have a list of 1600 words such that each number from 0 to 1600 corresponds to a word. I also have a very large matrix (1600 x 1600) that tells me (on a scale of 0 to 1) how related each word is to every other word. (These are from a latent semantic analysis; http://lsa.colorado.edu/)

I can make the lists, but it's not very efficient at all, and my adjacent words aren't super strongly related to each other.

### Here's my basic algorithm:

- Set thresholds for minimum value for how related the adjacent words must be and for how unrelated the non-adjacent words must be.
- Create a list from 0 to 1600. Shuffle that list. The first item of the list will be our first word.
- Loop through our words, checking one by one if the word meets our thresholds (i.e., check that this new word is high enough related to the last added word in the list, loop through our list and check that it's unrelated to all other words and that it isn't already in our list). If it meets the criteria, add it to the list. If we loop through all words with no success, dump the list and start all over.
- Continue this until the list has as many words as I want (ideally, 16).

Does anyone have a better approach? The problem with my approach is that I'll sometimes settle for an okay match that meets my criteria when a better match is potentially still out there. Also, it would be nice if I didn't have to dump the whole list but could backtrack a few steps to where the list potentially went wrong.

Comment: I'm just taking a random shot here, but it seems to me a good starting point would be to create a function to score word lists quantitatively. There may be an analytical solution out there, but right now I'm thinking you need a heuristic to go from.

Comment: Hmmm... I could sum up all the adjacent words values -- the higher this value, the more related my adjacent words are. Then, I could create another threshold value for that.But that doesn't help with any optimization.

Comment: Do you need it to always find the perfectly optimum solution or are you simply looking for better on average?

Comment: Try nltk Natural Language Toolkit from www.nltk.org . NLTK may already have something similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: Not necessarily the optimum, but better than what I'm getter right now. :)

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good candidate for a genetic algorithm. You can create a large number of completely random possibilities, score each one with an objective function, and then iterate the population by crossing over mates based on fitness (possibly throwing some mutations in as well).

If done properly, this should give you a large-ish population of good solutions. If the population is large enough, the fitness function defined well enough and mutation is sufficient to get you out of any valleys you might otherwise get stuck in, you might even converge overwhelmingly on the optimal answer.

Comment: This sounds intriguing but completely over my head. I'm working off of one computer science class back in my college days. Any helpful references?

Comment: This looks fairly accessible: http://www.ai-junkie.com/ga/intro/gat1.html . Basically, the way I see it working here is to create a collection of candidate lists and a function that quantifies how good a list is. Maybe it is the sum of products of adjacent similarities minus the sum of products of non-adjacent similarities? Then, you kill off some percentage of the population at each step, breed to achieve a similar population size by combining existing lists to get new ones, add some mutations in there, and iterate for a while.

Answer (score 0):

> Loop through our words...**If it meets the criteria, add it to the list.**

This seems to be the point of issue. You are stopping at the first match, not the *best* match. Using your 1600 square matrix of relatedness values, you can simply get the index of the maximum relatedness value for the remaining words, then go the word matrix and add the corresponding word to the list.

Comment: Right, so I've actually considered this approach. But it's leading me to a problem. Let's say that the best word to match SCHOOL to is CLASSROOM (and not CAFETERIA like I used above), but CLASSROOM doesn't have any words that relate to it and not SCHOOL. Then I lose all possibilities from here on out (including the successful CAFETERIA branch) because the best match for SCHOOL isn't the best option for the whole list.

Comment: Then you should consider a branching algorithm, which will assuredly require greater computational power, but will provide the results you are seeking.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution seems to be probabilistic. You're not looking for the absolute best lists, just a set of "good enough" lists.

1 - Pick a random starting word, add it to your list.

2 - Find the set of all highly related words (pick a sensible relatedness value based on your data). Pick one word randomly from the set of related words, make sure it doesn't relate too closely to any other words in the list. Loop this until you find one that works (then append it to your list and go back to 2 until you reach the desired list size) or exhaust all related words (discard your list and go back to 1).

3 - go back to 1 until you've constructed enough lists.

Answer (score 0):

Preprocess to a different data structure:Dictionary of lists by words.

Each dictionary gets a list, sorted low to high of related words (using your proximity matrix).

Pick random word for 1st.  2nd word is lowest word in 1st's list(closest match).

3rd word is picked from at/near the end of 1st' list - ie unrelated. 4th word is from start of 3rd word's list. Repeat.

Reread reqs - as you pick each word up (close match from left and non-match from right) you need to revisit the lists of the words picked so far and make sure that the candidate's position is far enough right i.e. low match) from words picked so far. If not advance 1 right (next closest) or 1 left (next furthest).